# Authenticate with Azure AD account while using Read-SqlTableData to read AzSQL tables

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, database-connection, smo

What other properties does one need to add to the `ConnectionContext` while connecting to [AzSQL using an **AzAD** account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-admin-with-a-server-in-sql-database)?

```
$srv = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "<>.database.windows.net"
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
$srv.ConnectionContext.Authentication = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo+AuthenticationMethod]::ActiveDirectoryPassword
$srv.ConnectionContext.Login = "<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com"
$srv.ConnectionContext.Password = "<>"
$srv.ConnectionContext.Connect()
```

**Error** :
`MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server <>.database.windows.net."`

The [ActiveDirectoryPassword method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.sqlconnectioninfo.authenticationmethod?view=sql-smo-160) works fine [from SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-mfa-ssms-overview#authentication-options). I'm trying to run [`Read-SqlTableData`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aa6fa4f-4fb3-48c6-b0a4-cc279090f0be/powershell-readwritesqltabledata-fails-connecting-to-azure-sql-database) instead of invoking a TSQL query.

```
Read-SqlTableData -InputObject $srv.Databases["TestDB"].Tables["TestTable"] -TopN 5
```

Expecting screenshot or screenclip GIF that the answer code is working for an AzAD **user**id on AzSQL using `Read-SqlTableData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An `AccessToken` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps#-accesstoken) has been added to the cmdlet in version `22.0.59` of the [SqlServer Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps).

```
Read-SqlTableData -AccessToken (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token `
-ServerInstance <>.database.windows.net -SchemaName dbo -DatabaseName <> -TableName <> -TopN 3 |FT
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in person, this is just because the Read-SqlTableData has not been updated (yet) to support an -AccessToken parameter.

I've already had a few requests for other cmdlets as well... so I'll try to get it as soon as I can.

Comment: Posting GitHub issue for tracking. [Make Read-SQLTableData AzureAD access token aware](https://github.com/microsoft/SQLServerPSModule/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to login as **administrator** .The user must have azure ad admin role for server to connect.

And make sure the user has **diretory readers role** from azure portal **IAM** access control.

Also Ensure that you've assigned an AAD admin for the SQL Server.
Try to create a service principal in azure ad if not already present and then give db_reader or db_writer or db_owner permissions granted .

```
CREATE USER [user or msi] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER <Azure_AD_principal_name>  --Grant the user db_datareader permissions on that database
GO
```

or write permission if required

```
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER <Azure_AD_principal_name>;
```

Or owner permission if required

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER <Azure_AD_principal_name>
```

Or [**Create Azure AD users in azure sql DB using service principals** - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-service-principal-tutorial?msclkid=302e5c72b9ce11ecb6ea2d9dcfba0886)

Please check below references:

1. [Adding a new user with specific permissions to an Azure Sql Database
   using Active Directory Integrated Authentication - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746160/adding-a-new-user-with-specific-permissions-to-an-azure-sql-database-using-activ?msclkid=302d88f4b9ce11ecb251262f732643e5)
2. [Connect an Azure App Registration to Azure SQL Database via
   Powershell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630473/connect-an-azure-app-registration-to-azure-sql-database-via-powershell?msclkid=21df8b22b9c811ecbb6fe9584f168987)

Comment: This is for a user; not an SPN. The user is [already an Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-portal). Creating user from external provider and granting permissions didn't help either.
```CREATE USER [<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GRANT select, update, delete ON [dbo].[TestTable] TO [<>@<>.onmicrosoft.com];
```
Maybe `$srv` is incomplete and the connection is failing.

Comment: You can give the user name itself in  `ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER <user>` : [Reference.](https://sqlitybi.com/how-to-create-azure-ad-users-on-azure-sql-database/?msclkid=fc7b5212b9d211ec988b43acf6d6d3ca).  OR  you may try to check if you may directly go to portal and give database related roles to that user from access control .

Comment: Adding as `db_owner` doesn't help either. It's not an RBAC issue. There is some issue with the `$srv.ConnectionContext`

Comment: Please check if server user name and password in connection string with authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword are given with `sql server credentials` and connection timeout and also check `azure ad username and password` are correct and are not expired. Also see [examples of some errors](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/examples-of-some-connection-errors-for-azure-active-directory/ba-p/386077?msclkid=46f533a1b9db11ecbfbc5806f0d83ba8) . Please refresh all and execute again.

Comment: I was unable to contact you on Teams. Is the code in the question working for you?